# Problemas para correr SDK (Emulador) en android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Hola que tal comunidad tengo el siguiente problema espero y me puedan ayudar, acabo de instalar Android Studio 3.0 y no me permite crear dispositivos virtuales me dice que el ADB es obsoleto que necesito actualizar la version

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui si me aparecen los aque agrego pero si le doy correr a esos solo me abre el dispositivo pero no me muestra la aplicacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui es donde me deberian de aparecer los creados incluso mi dispositivo si lo conecto sino mal recuerdo, pero ni uno ni otro me aparecen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Porque esta versión y no la 3.4.1? ¿Podrías mostrar la ventana de Android Studio donde indica la ruta del Android SDK?

Comment: Bueno había instalado la version 3.4.1 pero me presento el mismo error por eso instale la 3.0,ya solucione ese problema pero ahora no me deja crear el AVD me dice que el ADB es obsoleto

Comment: Cuando actualices Android Studio elimina el caché y evitaras problemas mediante File > Invalidate Caches/Restart @IsaiasAlejandroSanchez

Answer (score 1):

Cuando realices una actualización de Android Studio, es importante eliminar el caché en caso de tener problemas, para realizar la eliminación del caché mediante:

`File` > `Invalidate Caches/Restart`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Con respecto al error:

> Write access is allowed from event dispatch thread only

posiblemente no tienes instalado el JDK o estas usando otro JDK te sugiero uses el de la instalación

`File` > `Project Structure` y verifica que tengas seleccionado "Use embedded JDK".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Jorgesys pero ya hice y verifique lo que me comentas pero sigue sin aparecerme los dispositivos virtuales para ejecutar mis aplicaciones ¿A que se deberá? Te comento que si me aparecen pero no en la parte que ejecuta la aplicación adjunto foto para que me entiendas

Comment: Solo agrega las actualizaciones a tu pregunta, no elimines el contenido anterior.

Comment: Las elimine por que ya se soluciono ese error